# Why those 2 layout looks different?

Tags: android, html, layout

Can some one explain to me what is my misunderstanding? For both layout i have layout_height = 140dp . But why they looks different ? how can i fix that?

Here is a full xml's : https://www.pastiebin.com/59ad4fa3d00ba
https://www.pastiebin.com/59ad4fd6a20c0

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

First one is :

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/discount_apply"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="ПРИМЕНИТЬ" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/discount_cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="ОТМЕНИТЬ"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Second is :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CashButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/cash"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="НАЛИЧНЫЕ" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CardButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/visa"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="БАНКОВСКАЯ \n КАРТА" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In seond layout you are using weights

Comment: Yes i see, and this is really influences. But i thought that if i'm ussing android:layout_height it shuld be exect the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quiet difficult to tell from this much code but in the second layout, I see a layout_weight = 1 in the LinearLayout. If the parent of this LinearLayout is another LinearLayout with orientation set to vertical, this migth override your height setting.

Comment: Shold i delete layout_weight  tag and set android:layout_height for less value?

Comment: You should use either _weight or _height and not both. If you have a fixed height layout, then you should use layout_height and remove _weight.